# Module not founds: Can't resolve 'fs' from dependency packaged with rollup

Tags: javascript, module, fs, rollup

my rollup config:

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';

const extensions = ['.js', '.jsx'];

export default {
    input: 'src/index.js',
    output: [
        {
            dir: 'lib/cjs',
            format: 'cjs',
        },
        {
            dir: 'lib/esm',
            format: 'esm',
        },
    ],
    external: ['fs'], //i've tried with and without this
    plugins: [
        babel({
            extensions,
            exclude: 'node_modules/**',
        }),
        resolve(),
        commonjs(),
    ],
};
```

and I bundle up a package that uses `import fs from 'fs';`

When I pack it as 'my-dep' and try to use it in another project as a dependency, using the cjs

`const myDep = require("my-dep")`

works but using esm

`import myDep from 'my-dep'`

throws an error

`Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in <path-to-my-project>/my-dep/lib/cjs`

Comment: In what environment are you importing `my-dep`? Is it a node or browser project? Also, is it compiled/transpiled/bundled?